# How to close a UIView with an animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

When a button is clicked i display a `UIView` and it animates and slides up.

Now, when i click on button the method `buttoncall` gets called. 
I want to close (move down/close) the view with an animation. 
How can i do this ?

```
    v = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:mycell.bounds];

    [v.flipLowButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttoncall:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [mycell addSubview:v];

    CGRect r=v.frame;

    r.origin.y= mycell.frame.size.height;

    v.frame=r;

    rect.origin.y=r.origin.y-r.size.height;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{

     v.frame=r;    }];


- (void) buttoncall:(UIButton *)sender {

   // How to bring down the menu.

}
```

Comment: Just do the opposite of what you did to show the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bring the view down by its own height. 
For ex: If the view is shown 100px above from bottom, then just offset the view by +100px to get the dismiss effect.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{

     [v setFrame:CGRectOffset(v.frame, 0, CGRectGetHeight(v.bounds))];    
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same animation code you already have:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
     v.frame=r;    
}];
```

Just set `v.frame` to the new (or original) destination.

Comment: the animation is from bottom to top. And not top to bottom

Answer (score 0):

yourView.frame = CGRectMake(yourView.frame.origin.x, yourView.frame.origin.y, yourView.frame.size.width, yourView.frame.size.height);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

yourView.frame = CGRectMake(yourView.frame.origin.x, yourView.frame.origin.y + yourView.frame.size.height, yourView.frame.size.width, yourView.frame.size.height);

}];